# Is there a third party JavaScript that adds Facebook Chat style messaging to a site?

Tags: javascript, looking-for-a-script, ajax, plugin, chat

I'm looking for a service (happy to pay) that will provide Facebook style chat to users of my website. I'd expect it to work somewhat like Disqus but probably require a bit more work to implement user account integration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- [Commetchat](http://www.cometchat.com)
- [ArrowChat](http://www.arrowchat.com)

If you want whole facebook chat on your site.
Use facebook api or ebuddy that will give you facebook chat for only facebook users.

Comment: I don't want actual FB Chat, but something that works like FB chat with the user accounts on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Another one you can try is the open source [Ajax IM](http://ajaxim.com/). What you have to ask yourself is how many users will you have and can you handle the traffic. Especially when you want to have the chat server on your system. Else it would be better if you take an external service.

Answer (score -2):

Try [RumbleTalk](http://www.rumbletalk.com) HTML5 JS widget.
The main benefit is that you can stay connected also from your mobile.

The best of its kind

Comment: You are expected to [disclose affiliation](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) when promoting your own products. Please edit your response.